# Can't remove contacts from SIM card

Tags: java, android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver, sim-card

I've got a problem with removing contacts I previously created on SIM card.

First of all I'm checking what values are stored in DB like this:

```
private static final Uri URI_ICC_ADN = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn/");
private ContentResolver mContentResolver = this.getContentResolver();

Cursor c = mContentResolver.query(URI_ICC_ADN, null, null, null, null);
c.moveToFirst();
while(c.moveToNext()) {
     Log.i(LOG_TAG, "name = " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
}
```

And this provides me with those logs:

```
name = 1
name = 2
name = 3
name = 1
name = 2
name = 5
// etc
```

It means that records with `name = 1` exist in DB. Now I'm trying to delete those records with this code:

```
int rowsDeleted = mContentResolver.delete(URI_ICC_ADN, "name=?", new String[] { "1" });
```

But unfortunately those rows are not removed - `rowsDeleted` equals `0`. I've also tried this:

```
int rowsDeleted = mContentResolver.delete(URI_ICC_ADN, "name=1", null);
```

But the result is the same. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

"name" is only for read query. For deletion you have to pass "tag" for the name column. Check this link for the actual implementation [IccProvider](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/android-cts-4.2_r2/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/IccProvider.java)